# Russian chess school maxim: draw after loss (?)

Tags: history

I seem to remember a maxim attributed to the Russian chess school, "after two losses, draw the next game (however good the position may seem)". Does somebody know the exact saying and to whom it is attributed?

Comment: I have been in that situation. Many times, I have had 3 consecutive losses. If you made a draw, you feel like you are starting a new tournament. If you are too ambitious, maybe you can lose a new game, and instead of 2 losses, you would have 3 consecutive losses that is extremely hard from the psychological perspective. Or if you have had 3 consecutive losses, you would have 4, that is way harder than 3.